# Mod RewriteRule 1 Working, RewriteRule 2 Not Working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm starting out using mod rewrite to display search engine friendly URLs.

I have a page with left-hand column navigation links to display different categories.

When this page loads, it has default content being displayed in the right-hand column.

When one of the left-hand column links to a particular category is clicked, a list of all the product items for that specific category will be displayed. This will then replace the default content. When I hover over one of the category links, I do see the correct pattern in the URL at the bottom of the browser window.

The list of category products being displayed has a link to a separate product details page.

In my .htaccess file I have two rewriterules, namely:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*).php$ wheelchairs.php?scatnavID=$1&scatname=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*).php$ wheelchairs-product-details.php?fwjID=$1&fwjpermalink=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

When testing on my local server, clicking on one of the category links, will display a list of the relevant category products. The search engine friendly URL is being displayed. This now works as expected.

However, when I now click on a link to view the product details, I am not redirected to the details page. When I hover over the product links, I do see the correct pattern in the URL at the bottom of the browser window.

Instead the page default content is displayed. I have noticed in the address bar, but I now see the URL with the product details pattern.

I spent two days trying to correct this. Would greatly appreciate some advice to resolve this issue. Much appreciated.

Made the following change. Second RewriteRule working!

```
RewriteRule ^SubCategory/([0-9]+)/(.*).php$ wheelchairs.php?scatnavID=$1&scatname=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Your two `RewriteRule` patterns are identical. Is this a typo? If not, you'll need to differentiate the URLs sufficiently that the appropriate rule can be selected. The `[L]` in your first rule means that after it is matched, no other rules are checked, so your second rule can never be executed.

Comment: No typo. Adjusted the first RewriteRule. 
RewriteRule ^SubCategory/([0-9]+)/(.*).php$ wheelchairs.php?scatnavID=$1&scatname=$2 [L,NC,QSA] 
Kindly provide an example of how else to differentiate the URLs. Thanks @MattRaines